# Confused why this won't work - Oracle date declaration

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql

This leads into a cte in Oracle 11g:

```
declare 

STARTDATE DATE := '01/01/2017';

;with cte(Accounts) AS (....
```

This is the error I am getting:

> ORA-06550: line 10 column 1 PLS-00103:Encountered the symbol ";"

I need to declare a startdat and it needs to = the date provided.

Comment: did you intend to put the ; before with cte(Accounts) AS ( ...

Comment: you have 2 `;`, remove one

Comment: Okay maybe I am just doing this wrong   declare 
STARTPOSTDATE DATE;

BEGIN  
STARTPOSTDATE := '01/01/2017';

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you posted doesn't have a `begin` before tha `with`, and instead has an extra semicolon.

```
declare 
  startdate DATE := DATE '2017-01-01';
begin
  with cte(Accounts) AS (....
  ... complete that statement ... ;
end;
/
```

You can set the date value as part of the declaration; you shouldn't set it to a string though, as that relies on implicit conversion and NLS settings. I've used [a date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1), which has to be in exactly the format shown, YYYY-MM-DD; but `to_date()` would also work (a literal is simpler though, for a fixed date).

Comment: Does the end come at the end of that particular cte then- or at the end of the entire plsql script?  The variable is only in the first cte.  Thanks - that is much better, but I need to understand the end piece.

Comment: The `end;` is the end of [the PL/SQL block](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/overview.html#GUID-826B070B-4888-4398-889B-61A3C6B91349), matched up with the `declare` and the `begin`. The `with` is defining a CTE for a query and neither has its own `end`.

Comment: I am down to this error - bad date format, and I added the end; to the very end of everything:  declare 
  startdate DATE := DATE '2017/01/01';
begin
  with 
 cte(Accounts) AS

Comment: With a date literal the date has to be exactly as I showed it: `DATE '2017-01-01'`. You can't swap dashes and slashes.

Comment: Alex thank you for that explanation.  WHat if I wanted to use it as a input variable?  In SQL I would do @startdate and it would require someone to put in a date.

Comment: You can use a bind variable, or from SQL\*Plus etc. you could use a substitution variable, so it depends how you will call it. That's really a different question though...

Comment: Okay I am getting the bad format on this:  declare 
  startdate DATE :=  DATE '2017/01/01';

Comment: That's the same error you had earlier. Look back at the 3rd and 4th comments.

Comment: Make sure your DATE literal matches the format specified in NLS_DATE_FORMAT.  Mine happens to be DD-MON-RR.   Or, just use to_date with a format string ;-)

Comment: @muffntuf - no, you said (twice) that you are using `DATE '2017/01/01'` which is not the same as `DATE '2017-01-01'`. You *must* use dashes with a date literal, not slashes. (And it does *not* use NLS settings, that kind of the point *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole are you sure about it not using NLS_DATE_FORMAT?  Seems to on my instance (11.2), but I could be missing something obvious.

Comment: @tbone - [yes, I'm sure](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f706bd2dcd4dc4bc3870d532f8f40eb9). The docs (link in answer) also say it has to be that (ANSI) format. Maybe you're omitting the `DATE` keyword, so you're just converting a string implicitly, which *would* rely on NLS?

Answer (score 0):

For what I see code, you have to remove the semicolon that is before the statement WITH

Comment: Please see the comment above yours.  What is the correct syntax?  Everything I have done I get that error.

Comment: The answer of @alexpoole gives perfectly the correct syntax